# Xamarin clickable substring in custom label

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am trying to make it so users can click a certain substring in a label and it would run a method, for example clicking **#hashtag** would run `OpenHashtag(string hashtag`and clicking a **@taggedUser** would run `ViewProfile(taggedUser)`

I found [this](https://theconfuzedsourcecode.wordpress.com/2016/03/10/so-i-created-this-awesomehyperlinklabel-custom-renderer-control-one-day-for-xamarin-forms/) tutorial, except I don't want phone numbers or URLs to be clickable, only hashtags and tagged users.

These are the renders its using

**Android**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(BodyLabel), typeof(BodyLabelAndroid))]
namespace SocialNetwork.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class BodyLabelAndroid : LabelRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            var view = (BodyLabel)Element;
            if (view == null) return;

            TextView textView = new TextView(Forms.Context);
            textView.LayoutParameters = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WrapContent, LayoutParams.WrapContent);
            textView.SetTextColor(view.TextColor.ToAndroid());

            // Setting the auto link mask to capture all types of link-able data
            textView.AutoLinkMask = MatchOptions.All;
            // Make sure to set text after setting the mask
            textView.Text = view.Text;
            textView.SetTextSize(ComplexUnitType.Dip, (float)view.FontSize);

            // overriding Xamarin Forms Label and replace with our native control
            SetNativeControl(textView);
        }
    }
}
```

**IOS**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(BodyLabel), typeof(BodyLabeliOS))]
namespace SocialNetwork.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class BodyLabeliOS : ViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<View> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            var view = (AwesomeHyperLinkLabel)Element;
            if (view == null) return;

            UITextView uilabelleftside = new UITextView(new CGRect(0, 0, view.Width, view.Height));
            uilabelleftside.Text = view.Text;
            uilabelleftside.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize((float)view.FontSize);
            uilabelleftside.Editable = false;

            uilabelleftside.DataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorType.All;
            uilabelleftside.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;

            SetNativeControl(uilabelleftside);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You will not be able to use these solutions (at least as far as Andriod is concerned). The andriod features they are enabling are from  https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Text.Util.MatchOptions/ and obviously they dont support hash tags, you will have to make a very specific renderer which im guessing wont be trivial (but possible), Or find a premade solution which you can adapt which has a more granular approach

Comment: The best way to do this would be to add a gesture recognizer on the label. I am not quite sure why you chose a custom renderer, but I saw you tagged the question with xamarin.forms. If you have built the solution in xamarin forms, then adding a gesture recognizer that executes a command would be trivial.

Comment: @SpookKruger If I added a gesture recognizer it would make the whole label only direct to that one, what if there are two hashtags or two tagged users in a post?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android:

Instead of using  `textView.AutoLinkMask = MatchOptions.All`
you can use 
[Linkify.AddLinks](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Text.Util.Linkify.AddLinks/p/Android.Widget.TextView/Java.Util.Regex.Pattern/System.String/) method. Define your regular expression (for example, any word which starts with # or @) and it will work.

But on iOS, it is more complicated I think.
There I see two options:

1. Use WebView. Parse your string and add `"<a href"` where needed.
2. Break your text to pieces and add separate labels for each clickable part. If you want to click only hashtags and tagged users you can add the appropriate labels just below the text. Afterwards you can add tap gesture recognizers to handle the clicks.

Comment: How do I tell it which method to run when clicked?